# python-config missing

Tags: python

I'm installing a program that requires I have python-config installed.  The only problem is that I do not currently have python-config, and I cannot seem to figure out how to get it.

After searching around, I can supposedly install it via:

```
yum install python-devel
```

However, after doing so, python-config still does not exist.

I am currently using Python 2.4 on a cluster running CentOS 5.2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I can tell it did.

Is there another package I'm missing?

Comment: I would suggest strying to install python-confid from pip.  Does pip work for Python2.4?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue running CentOS 8 with python 3.6.  python3-config is installed and not python-config. you can either create a symlink or just use python3-config .

Comment: Hi, this is a very old question, please consider leaving a comment instead of a proper answer next time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it installed the file somewhere else.

First do:

```
         which python
```

on command line to find where the executable file is located.

Second:

Compare the installation file folder to see if it is in the same place.

Third:

if not you can either move it to the same folder or use the executable pointed by your file by calling it from the top of your scripts. 
It should look something like this:

```
       #!/usr/bin/Python-2.7.11
```

Resist changing the python version of your cluster, calling it from your script with a locally installed version seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

d/l from http://www.red-dove.com/config-0.3.9.tar.gz

or from http://www.red-dove.com/config-0.3.9.win32.exe

unpack and use setup.py

Answer (score 0):

Jason's reply may solve your missing dependency issue though more information is required regarding how you are installing your main package which needs python-config as its dependency.

If installation is done via yum or directly from rpm files and rpm package has python-config as its dependency then even if you install python config from setup.py file missing package error wouldn't go away. In this case you may have to do force install using yum or rpm or install main application via different method.

Regards,

Comment: It is via a configure script.  The program itself requires the python developers libraries being installed, and checks to see if you have them installed via python-config.

Answer (score 0):

`yum install python-configparser`

FYI, if you install `python3` via IUS, the equivalent python-config is `/usr/lib64/python3.6/configparser.py`. You may need to create a symlink by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
yum remove python38-devel
```

and reinstall it:

```
yum install python38-devel.
```

Comment: Hello, please add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.