# What do compiler commands mean?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, command, rules

I want to execute [Forpy](https://github.com/ylikx/forpy) interoperability.

In [Get started](https://github.com/ylikx/forpy#getting-started) part, following commands are employed:

```
# Python 3.8 and higher
gfortran -c forpy_mod.F90
gfortran intro_to_forpy.F90 forpy_mod.o `python3-config --ldflags --embed`
```

What do they mean?

Are they write for Linux/Unix or they can employ in windows?

If they write for Linux/Unix, What is a similar command for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler commands are like inputs for the processing entity behind the command. The command can be anything and so does the inputs so I think the type of processing entity can be different for different os but the inputs would be the same. So if u have gfortran installed on your windows system then the same command would work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give more description about this part:" `python3-config --ldflags --embed` ". I have GNU but when I build the code this part shows errors.

Comment: Please check if the package is installed properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407120/python-config-missing

Comment: I have three types of python in three kinds. Consequently, "python3-config" not find is ridiculous. Plus errors are also about "--ldflags" and "--embed".